# AppleScript : cleaning text

Tags: applescript

Is there a way to remove some occurrence of a variable within a text without knowing where the variable is in the text ?

e.g :

> IP= DA, null,
>
> var to be removed from the text : ***", null,"***

I know in this actual example I could trim using this

```
set newText to text 1 thru -8 of var1
```

Or even with a text delimiter, but I need to remove the variable from a random text without knowing where the variable is within the text

Comment: Why AppleScript? BTW "IP= DA, null," is not an AppleScript method of assigning the value of a variable. I'd use `sed`, e.g. `sed 's/, null,//'` where e.g., `sed 's/, null,//'<<<'IP= DA, null,'` returns: `IP= DA`

Comment: Thank you.  how would I place the variable on the sed command ? I tested with :  
do shell script "sed 's/, null,//' <<<" & input but this return an error. (PS my text is a long text generated by the same AppleScript with including  IP= RANDOM, null, within the text)

Comment: Never-mind, it's working : do shell script "sed 's/, null,//' <<<'" & input & "'" Thank you again